# iFrame resized dynamically don't show entire page

Tags: javascript, html

I'm using this script to set the height of my iframe based on content height size, but i need to click twice on the menu, to show the entire content.

Look here: http://www.luilui.com.br/inverno2013

Anyone knows why?

my page that contains the iframe script:

```
<iframe name="iframe_site" id="iframe_site" src="inicio.asp" width="100%" scrolling="no" height="100%" marginheight="0" frameborder="0" ></iframe>
```

this is on the pages inside iframe:

```
<body id="size">
.
.
.
.
content
.
.
.
.

    <script language="Javascript" type="text/javascript">

      var _iframe = parent.document.getElementById("iframe_site"),
          _height = _iframe.contentDocument.getElementById("size").scrollHeight || _iframe.contentWindow.document.getElementById("size").scrollHeight;
          _iframe.height = _height + 40;
    </script>
</body>
```

EDITED: I do not know if this helps, but only the page inicio.asp appears complete, that is the page I call in the iframe tag

Comment: Can look here the problem: http://www.luilui.com.br/inverno2013

Answer (score 0):

Using `window.setTimeout` i have fixed that problem....

```
<script language="Javascript" type="text/javascript">
    window.setTimeout( 

        function(){
            var _iframe = parent.document.getElementById("iframe_site"),
            _height = _iframe.contentDocument.getElementById("size").scrollHeight || _iframe.contentWindow.document.getElementById("size").scrollHeight;
            _iframe.height = _height;
        },

    2000);
</script>
```